# Simple rust "match" implementation in TypeScript. How to type the function?

Tags: typescript, types, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement a simple version of [match from Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html)

It should work like this:

```
const value = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 'foo'
 
const result = match(value, {
  1: () => 100,
  foo: () => 'F'
})
  
result // 100 | 'F'
```

1. In object argument - keys must cover all the possible types of `value` (`1` and `'foo'` in example above) - otherwise TS should throw an error, that a particular property is missing.
2. In object argument - values must be functions - otherwise TS should throw an error that value is not assignable to function
3. The "default case" is not important, I will try to implement it later

The best approach I have get:

```
export function match<
  Case extends string | number,
  Options extends Record<Case, any>
>(case: Case, options: Options): ReturnType<Options[Case]> {
  return options[case]()
}
```

This workaround with `any` keyword has one major problem - the code can break at runtime. When I try to type somehow this `any` - I always end up with return type `any` or `unknown`.

(I know about conditional types and infer, but this knowledge doesn't help me in this case...)

How to type this match function?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overload your function:

```js
function match<
  Key extends PropertyKey,
  ReturnValue extends string | number,
  Branch extends () => ReturnValue,
  Options extends Record<Key, Branch>,
  Variant extends keyof Options
>(options: Options, variant: Variant): ReturnType<Options[Variant]>
function match(options: Record<PropertyKey, () => unknown>,variant: PropertyKey, ) {
  return options[variant]()
}


const result1 = match({
  1: () => 100,
  foo: () => 'F'
}, 1) // 100

const result2 = match({
  1: () => 100,
  foo: () => 'F'
}, 'foo') // snumber
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgLYEMZQBYB5jLIDSApgJ7IkAeMJEAJgM7IAKATggA4lsxmlkANAWQAlEjDBsIANXQAbMCUo06TZIxhs4EAObIAPsghhUAIx7DCAITbpo2FbQbMAFAEpkAXgB8YiVKyCkpWyADynPBIzNTO6uJQCGz0uAKCyLb2OD6hctr2ME5qzADW5Agg4ZGIEIzAPq5cUbUAXFXNjOkAbuj5EDBteXAF7m3iktIAKmTcuBEdANpDBQC6PqCQsDVomDiN1dFjJInJuOxcPHxpyB7efpAlEAgA7hA5PX0DrBzcvPzk6U8AG8RGwAtJkE0aowFh9hv0Vh5gABfYBoxK1QpgxhgeQwACM3h2WGwrhBhHxbVuvmQ+IADHTQiAEAgqZ4aQByABiHJR6XxngA9ILaQz0dEsSQcXiAExEjAkskiSk3dl+emMkTM1mqu7Ibm85HpDnajlCkWMEzmHhooA)

I know, I have used `unknown`, but I did not use it in my overload signature. If you hover your mouse on `match` you will see that each object key/value is infered.

In order to infer literal type, you should either use literal object as a first argument or make it immutable.

I believe making it immutable is a way to go, since I assume it will be used in a several functions:

```js
function match<
  Key extends PropertyKey,
  ReturnValue,
  Branch extends () => ReturnValue,
  Options extends Record<Key, Branch>,
  Variant extends keyof Options
>(options: Options, variant: Variant): ReturnType<Options[Variant]>
function match(options: Record<PropertyKey, () => unknown>, variant: PropertyKey,) {
  return options[variant]()
}

const strategy = {
  1: () => 100 as 100,
  foo: () => 'F' as 'F'
} as const

const result1 = match(strategy, 1) // 100

const result2 = match(strategy, 'foo') // F
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgLYEMZQBYB5jLIDSApgJ7IkAeMJEAJgM7IAKATggA4lsxmlkANAWQAlEjDBsIANXQAbMCWGEAQm3TRslGnSbIAFAEpkAXgB8YiVNkKlK5AHlO8JM2q0GzcVARt6uAKCyOqaOOYOcmxwmjA6nvoA1uQIIE4uiBCMwOYGXK5ZAFzpBYzBAG7o0bHFUTEQMEbF4pLSACpk3LjOpQDadbEAuuagkLCZaJg4eRluzSS%20-rjsXDx8QYYmFsiQiRAIAO4QEciV1Q3FK9y8-OSCJgDeImzW0sj5mYy9Z-Uwg8bAAC%20wGAviycUYMA0tAA5hRTMgnoQAIzFYxmSzIgAMWOQ6GY2KxDhACAQaK2lgA5AAxSl45g0ylA%20nIMGQkFsuIvRhgeQwZFmSZYbAGSHQkhw4LIkwAehlyEJHLcXJIPL5ACZBRhhaKoZgJUJkJSSQhKbL5dSQUA)

If you want to learn more about function inference on arguments you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: There is a difference. In your implementation the `result` is type of `string`. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIZQgCwDwChGIDCqAzgKaJkAeUZYAJiYiVAE4xgDmiAPomCGQAjMqwA0+RAHkADrARNqtBkwBKZCHFb1sxcmMSowATwB8uUwAoIpAFxFSZA3DnwwJe7PnuAlPfVQIKxgACrGMmTYXm4kANp6ZAC6pogA3pKsZIHBiC7ecTYkiZY+uAC+uLia7lCImSQgADa1ALwo6FiWAOTAcHBdBukEvXD2JYgtKV0AYl3lpbhAA) the `result` is type of `'F'`. How to achieve this? Maybe I don't understand something...

Comment: @Argeento made an update

Comment: Everything works perfectly! Thank you!